# Make unique NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm currently enumerating through `NSMutableArray` (or `NSMutableSet`) elements to find duplicates and remove them.

For example, if array/set has values `[@"a", @"b", @"b", @"c"]`, the end result should be `[@"a", @"b", @"c"]`.

Since I'm comparing `NSStrings`, I'm using `isEqualTo:` method to check if strings are equal.

Is there a more efficient way to do remove duplicate entries than to loop through all of them and check if duplicate exists?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

An `NSSet` does exactly what you're trying to do: it is a (unordered) collection of unique items. So, you can find the unique items in your array like so:

```
NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];

// iterate over the unique items
for(id element in uniqueElements) {
  // do something
}
```

`NSSet` most likely uses a hash algorithm to make insertion O(1) (compared to O(n^2) to check if each item is unique by iteration), but the Apple documentation does not make such a guarantee so you probably shouldn't count on that implementation detail.

If, for some reason you need to keep the unique items in a sorted (ordered) collection, you can turn the set back into an array with `-[NSSet allObjects]` and then sort the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I did this to get unique elements in the array:

// add to set to check for unique element names
NSSet *uniqueNames = [NSSet setWithArray:names];
 
// return data back to the array
names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[uniqueNames allObjects]];

Comment: The more cannonical way to get back to the array names would be:
id names = [[uniqueNames allObjects] retain]; //if you want to keep names
or
id names = [uniqueNames allObjects]; //if you don't want to retain ownership of the array

Comment: @BarryWark wouldn't it be O(n) for the iteration?

Comment: @JackyBoy my algorithms classes are a lot of years ago now, but I believe inserting `m` elements into an `n` element array naively (i.e. the array is unsorted) would be `O(m*n) ~ O(n^2)`, but please correct the post if I'm wrong!

Comment: From my understanding, it don't think you can `O(m*n) ~ O(n^2)` only if `m -> n` (worst case possible). But normally I think that what Big O considers is the bigger one between `m` and `n`. I might be wrong, just did want to confirm with you actually.

Comment: @JackyBoy I *think* you're right. In this case (finding duplicates), it's m = n, however, no?

Comment: If n `@[1,3,5,7,8]` and m `@[2,4,6,8]` and you want to insert m into n : You will need @ minimum 2 cycles inside each other. But in that case where you want to check if a given array doesn't has any duplicates it would be `O(n^2)`. You are right!

Answer (score 5):

An `NSSet` or `NSMutableSet` will guarantee that you don't have duplicate objects. It will work for `NSStrings` as in your example, but for your own classes keep in mind what do you mean by "equal" and implement the `hash` and `isEqual:` methods accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's good to know that it's automatic for NSStrings.

Answer (score 3):

A set never contains duplicate elements, so simply creating an `NSMutableSet` should guarantee uniqueness of values.

Answer (score 1):

Only this line of code will work fine .

```
NSSet *mySet = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];
```

now mySet will have unique elements.