# How to remove items with duplicate field value from mutablearray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, duplicates

A mutablearray populated with items from a table with 3 fields (class number, lessons and started). I want to keep only one of the items with the same class number, say in one case, there are 3 objects with same class number.
What is the best way to remove any of the two items.

Comment: For example, there are 3 objects as below. The second and third objects are not exactly the same. They only have the same class number. I want to remove one of them, so that I shall have only one class 2.

class number (1) lessons (15) started (4th), 
class number (2) lessons (16) started (4th),
class number (2) lessons (17) started (5th).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily google it. Let me do it for you.
See the following example :

[**Removing duplicate values from NSMutable**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

[**Second example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858649/how-to-remove-duplicate-value-in-nsmutablearray)

[**Remove Duplicates in NSMutableArray**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/68856-remove-duplicates-in-nsmutablearray/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I saw these posts. I thought it can not solve my problem. It only removes duplicate objects and not duplicate of one of the field value.

Comment: The following example only remove duplicate object? My problem is duplicate field values but the objects are not exactly the same.

Comment: NSArray *copy = [mutableArray copy];
NSInteger index = [copy count] - 1;
for (id object in [copy reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    if ([mutableArray indexOfObject:object inRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)] != NSNotFound) {
        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index--;
}
[copy release];