# How to grouping the date strings without duplicate in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my apps, i have stored the date values into the Mutable Array which i retrieved from the server. Now i want to grouping the date, which means it should display the date as only once, when duplicate date as found.

For Eg,

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"December 29,2010", 
                                                                    @"December 28, 2010",
                                                                    @"December 22, 2010",
                                                                    @"December 22, 2010",
                                                                    @"December 22, 2010", nil];
```

And then i want to display the contents are date wise. so how can i compare the date strings and stored into separate arrays(With different dates). So please guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this SO post has answer for you.

[The best way to remove duplicate values from NSMutableArray in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025674/the-best-way-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c)

The following link is also informative.

[Make unique NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160898/make-unique-nsmutablearray-or-nsmutableset/1160938#1160938)